# Not receiving previous messages in nodejs mqtt reconnect

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, mqtt, amazon-mq

I'm creating a simple NodeJS app (as consumer) that receives messages from MQ Broker (Amazon MQ). I was able to receive the messages but when the publisher sends a message to the broker, the consumer does not read the new message (after a couple of minutes of being idle because of no new messages). Eventually, it disconnects and reconnects but at that moment it will only receive new published messages.

[image]

Here you can see that message numbers (8,9,12) are not being read. Is this a problem with my consumer app or it has something to do with the publisher or broker?

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const connect_mqtt = async () => {
  const host = 'SOME_HOST';
  const options = {
    username: 'SOME_USER',
    password: 'SOME_PASSWORD',
    clientId: 'mqttjs_' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8),
    keepalive: 1000
  };

  const client = mqtt.connect(host, options);

  client.on('error', function (error) {
    console.error('Connection Error:', error);
  });

  client.on('disconnect', function (error) {
    console.error('Disconnected', error);
  });

  client.on('close', function (error) {
    console.error('Connection Closed', error);
  });

  client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connecting...');
    client.subscribe('pass-log', function (error) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log('Connected!');
      } else {
        console.error('Subscription Error', error);
      }
    });
  });

  client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    if (topic === 'pass-log') {
      console.log('Consume', topic, message.toString());
    } else {
      console.log('NOT YOUR TOPIC');
    }
  });
};
connect_mqtt();
```

As checked from the ActiveMQ, connection is active
[image]

**UPDATE1:**

I added `keepalive, clean, reconnectPeriod, qos` from `options` matching from the publisher and it seems to work now. I'll do further observation on this.

**UPDATE2:**

I purposely disconnected the subscriber by exiting my node app while the publisher is sending message to topic. When I re/connect the subscriber, it only reads the last message.

Comment: Why is your client being disconnected? A MQTT client should happily sit connected to the broker even with no messages being published?

Comment: @hardillb, I'm also wondering why. I tried turning off my internet and reconnect but didn't received any console errors specified. I play around with keepalive option to see if issue persist.

Comment: First off, if you do not want your client to timeout, you need to add the `keepalive: 60000,` line to your `options` variable to enable the PINGREQ function in the node.js MQTT module.  Secondly, you are only subscribing to `pass-log` topic. So if your publisher(s) are sending to `pass-log/id/etc` your code will never receive them.  Maybe you want to subscribe to `pass-log/#`??

Comment: Hi @JDAllen, yes I added `keepalive` and still got the same behavior. As of the moment, I am only testing one subscriber so the topic `pass-log` is enough for now.

Comment: Any update on this guys, as I am also facing this issue in production. I am using `async-mqtt` npm. It is not able to reconnect with broker. Any solution ?